# A method for listing Ansible modules used by playbooks

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

I'm creating a `requirements.yml` in an Ansible project, and I want to identify all of the modules that need to be installed from `ansible-galaxy` that are used by project playbooks. `ansible-doc --list --playbook-dir foo` *seems* like the right tool for the job, but it lists **all** locally available modules, not just the ones which are actually used in the `foo` directory. `ansible-galaxy list` doesn't account for any which are needed but not installed.

Is there a way to do this where I don't end up writing a shell script to `sed|awk|grep` the info I want?

---

The best approach I've been able to come up with so far is to `ansible-playbook --syntax-check` each of the playbooks. This will throw errors such as

```
ERROR! the role 'foo' was not found ...
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'bar'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.
```

but this is not ideal because it exits as soon as any error occurs. I have to fix each one and run the syntax check again.

Comment: That problem sounds astronomically hard. Are your playbooks so massive that it's unreasonable to actually audit them? Alternatively, sure, the iterative version is wasteful, but it _will_ eventually do what you want, right?

Comment: The project playbooks, for the most part, are not excessively long, though the project has quite a lot of playbooks and roles. You are right, I was eventually able to suss out all of the dependencies using the iterative method. I also made sure that the repository will run a `--check-syntax` on all playbooks as part of CI to catch any requirements added in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, as a concept, the playbook below lists the modules used in a role

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    keywords:
      - always
      - become
      - block
      - loop
      - loop_control
      - name
      - notify
      - register
      - tags
      - vars
      - when

  tasks:

    - name: The variable my_role_path is mandatory
      assert:
        that: my_role_path|d('')|length > 0

    - name: Find tasks files
      find:
        path: "{{ my_role_path }}/tasks"
        patterns: '*.yml,*.yaml'
        recurse: true
      register: result

    - name: Create list of tasks
      set_fact:
        lft: "{{ lft|d([]) + lookup('file', item)|from_yaml }}"
      loop: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"

    - name: Get list of keys
      set_fact:
        lfk: "{{ lfk|d([]) + item.keys()|list }}"
      loop: "{{ lft }}"

    - name: Get list of keys from block/rescue/always
      set_fact:
        lfk: "{{ lfk|d([]) + item.keys()|list }}"
      loop: "{{ lft|json_query('[].[block, rescue, always]')|flatten }}"

    - name: Display list of modules
      debug:
        var: lfk|unique|sort|difference(keywords)
```

For example, analyze the role [systemd](https://galaxy.ansible.com/0x0i/systemd)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e my_role_path=roles/ansible-role-systemd

...

  lfk|unique|sort|difference(keywords):
  - command
  - file
  - include_tasks
  - meta
  - systemd
  - template
```

Complete the list of the [keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords).

---

Use the tasks below to analyze a playbook

```yaml
  tasks:

    - name: The variable my_playbook_path is mandatory
      assert:
        that: my_playbook_path|d('')|length > 0

    - name: Create list of tasks
      set_fact:
        lft: "{{ _playbook|map(attribute='tasks')|flatten }}"
      vars:
        _playbook: "{{ lookup('file', my_playbook_path)|from_yaml }}"

    - name: Get list of keys
      set_fact:
        lfk: "{{ lfk|d([]) + item.keys()|list }}"
      loop: "{{ lft }}"

    - name: Get list of keys from block/rescue/always
      set_fact:
        lfk: "{{ lfk|d([]) + item.keys()|list }}"
      loop: "{{ lft|json_query('[].[block, rescue, always]')|flatten }}"

    - name: Display list of modules
      debug:
        var: lfk|unique|sort|difference(keywords)
```

For example, analyzing the first playbook gives

```yaml
  lfk|unique|sort|difference(keywords):
  - assert
  - debug
  - find
  - set_fact
```

Comment: Very cool. I like that you used ansible to find the solution! XD